# Do I need Readyboost and page file if I have lots of free RAM?

Tags: windows, memory, performance, virtual-memory, readyboost

I have 12 GB RAM installed in my laptop. I have currently both page file and ready boost disabled. Most of the time my RAM usage are under 6 GB. So, I still have 6 GB RAM all the time. Considering this situation when I have lots of RAM do I need features like Virtual memory and Readyboost. Will they be any helpful to me?

Comment: Disabling pagefile will lead to out-of-memory errors when using memory-intensive applications.

Comment: @kinokijuf I never had face such situation after upgrading to 12 GB so far. So, I don't think I have to worry about it

Comment: @kinokijuf And how likely is that to happen when most of the time he has 6GB free? Also it can still easily happen with a page file - it just increases the limit.

Comment: @Brett Without a pagefile, the system has to reserve all memory that is asked by applications, even if it is never written to.

Answer (score 1):

Readyboost is effectively a complimentary technology to SuperFetch which caches as much data as possible from the hard drive in RAM, instead of using RAM Readyboost uses flash memory.

Readyboost is most effective on machines that are memory starved (<1GB RAM) as the flash memory is (for certain operations) faster than the hard drive.

On machines with a large amount of physical memory the performance boost of ReadyBoost is negligible.

[HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/123780/htg-explains-is-readyboost-worth-using/) agrees with me on this, There is also a recent benchmark on [7tutorials](http://www.7tutorials.com/does-readyboost-work-does-it-improve-performance-slower-pcs) that suggests that any improvement is marginal (at best) and highly dependant on workload for machines with plenty of RAM.  You may see some slight improvement in the load times for programs you regularly run at startup and you may save a second or two in boot times, but other than that the benefits are slim.

Answer (score 0):

Readyboost is great for helping to lower Disk I/O on drive intensive applications like Visual Studio, Photoshop etc - however it will do absolutely nothing to help improve performance in environments such as gaming which do a lot of calculations on the fly and don't read/write aggressively to the drive.

Since you have a heap of spare RAM available - I would recommend not using it unless you are using apps which do a lot of read/write like program compilation, sql queries or other such tasks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have never crossed 10 GB of RAM so far but I use I/O intensive applications and a lot of time task manager show hard disk usage as 100%. So, Does it mean I should readyboost? Isn't RAM enough to solve this problem?

Comment: RAM will solve files already open into RAM - but if an app requires a lot of IO, readyboost will help further.  For something to be quickly available in RAM, it first has to be read off the drive.  I can only really suggest turning it on and testing.  You can always disable again

Answer (score 0):

Readyboost is most useful for systems that don't have a whole lot of RAM, but it can still speed up your computer depending on many factors such as whether or not you have an SSD, how many times you use the same applications, how much the tasks you are performing use small (4k) reads, and the device you are using for Readyboost. If you don't have at least 1 free USB 3.0 slot, I wouldn't bother, but if you do, or perhaps even USB 3.1 or higher, then yes it could certainly help your machine unless you already have an SSD, in which case only an SD or USB stick with absurdly fast Access times and read/write speeds would have much effect on tasks that need even very large amounts of random reads.

In short, I would need more information in order to properly answer your question. And if you do use Readyboost there is a rather specific way that I would recommend you use it. With an NTSF file formatting system, and using a 3.0 32 GB USB stick or SD card with the removal policy set to "better performance" with the caveat that even I do not fully understand Readyboost. But in theory this will result in better performance then if left on quick removal due to the way Cache hits and misses work.